# How to filter embedded Power BI Report on MS Dynamics Customer Portal

Tags: powerbi, liquid, adxstudio-portals

I'm trying to dynamically filter my embedded Power BI report using liquid tags ,on a MS Dynamic Customer Portal.

I've changed the authentication type from "`powerbiembedded`" to "`AAD`" and the filtering works as expected. As well as removing and adding the ampersand symbol i.e. "&"

```
{% capture pbi_path %} https://app.powerbi.com/groups/GUID/reports/GUID/ReportSection?&$filter=accounts/name+eq+ '{{user.parentcustomerid.name}}' {% endcapture %}
{% powerbi authentication_type:"powerbiembedded" path:pbi_path %}
```

I expected the filtering to work as it did when the authentication type is "`AAD`" i.e the report is displayed and filtered. However, all that happens is the report is displayed without the filtering.

Comment: Check the filtering pane - is there an error that the filter is not valid?

Comment: @AndreyNikolov There are no errors

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the &$

so your code should be:

{% capture pbi_path %} https://app.powerbi.com/groups/GUID/reports/GUID/ReportSection?filter=accounts/name+eq+ '{{user.parentcustomerid.name}}' {% endcapture %}
{% powerbi authentication_type:"powerbiembedded" path:pbi_path %}